# Easy kivy app work on windows but not on Android

Tags: android, python, kivy, android-logcat

I'm trying to study Kivy, so I've done a simple gui that work on windows but when I run it on Android with Kivy Launcher I'm getting this error trought ADB LOGCAT :
[image]

This is a simple kv code :

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
<ROT>:
  FloatLayout:
     AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x:"center"
        anchor_y: "top"

        Button:
            size_hint : 1,1
            text : "prova"
            on_press: root.press()
```

and this is the main.py :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ROT(Widget):
    def press(self):
        print "ciao"
    pass

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('questionario.kv')
        return ROT()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

I can't understand why it doesn't want to work

Comment: No one knows why?

Comment: It works for windows, it works for linux (i tested it)... maybe it's kivy launcher's fault. Try building an `.apk` with buildozer. I'm pretty sure it will run.